# How to use non-standard ports?

Tags: moovweb

I'm trying to get moov running on port 8080 but am getting the error:

```
$ curl -s -i http://mlocal.nytimes.com:8080/
HTTP/1.0 534 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain;
Content-Length: 69

Host header 'mlocal.nytimes.com:8080' did not match project rewriters
```

I'm starting the server with:

```
$ sudo moov server -p=8080 --auto-hosts
```

(It appears to work fine on port 80.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an additional step you need to take when you manually specify a port to run on.

Go into the project files and open config.json

Append :8080 to the domain names specified like this:

"$.nytimes.com:8080 => www.nytimes.com",

etc..

Comment: Yup and you may have to restart the server! Don't forget to take out those port specifications when you push to the Moovweb Cloud.